# Erro ao ler %f e %e de um arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo, float, inteiros

No seguinte trecho do meu código tenho que ler uma função de um arquivo txt e extrair seus coeficientes. Quando coloco os coeficientes como inteiros e lendo-os com `%d` funciona corretamente, mas ao colocar os coeficientes com ponto flutuante ou até mesmo inteiro e lendo com `%f` ou `%e` o número que é lido é um número totalmente aleatório, como se fosse lixo. Gostaria de saber o porquê disso.

Lendo isso `1x1+2x2` da seguinte maneira dá certo. (`nVar` é a quantidade de variáveis que a função é formada, esse número é informado por uma linha do arquivo)

```
while(indice < nVar)
{                           
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&i);
    c1 = fgetc(fp);
    c2 = fgetc(fp);
    printf("%d%c%c; ",i,c1,c2);
    indice++;
}
```

mas lendo a função `1.5x1+2.3x2` ou até mesmo `1x1+2x2` da seguinte maneira as variáveis e seus índices são lidos corretamente, mas para os coeficientes um número aleatório como lixo é lido

```
while(indice < nVar)
{                           
    fscanf(fp,"%f",&x);
    c1 = fgetc(fp);
    c2 = fgetc(fp);
    printf("%f%c%c; ",x,c1,c2);
    indice++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nao estou conseguindo reproduzir o seu erro.

Esse codigo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* int i; */
    float x;
    char c1, c2;
    int ind = 0;
    while (ind < 2) {
        /* fscanf(stdin,"%d",&i); */
        fscanf(stdin,"%f",&x);
        c1 = fgetc(stdin);
        c2 = fgetc(stdin);
        printf("%f%c%c; ",x,c1,c2);
        ++ind;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

quando eu passo como entrada 1x1+2x2 imprime:

➜  /tmp  ./a.out
1x1+2x2
1.000000x1; 2.000000x2; %

Ja quando eu tiro o comentario do primeiro fscanf e comento o segundo, ele imprime:

➜  /tmp  ./a.out
1x1+2x2
1x1; 2x2; %

Se voce puder me dar um exemplo de entrada diferente eu posso tentar entender melhor o problema. :|

Colocando a entrada em um arquivo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char c1, c2;
    int ind = 0;
    float x;
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while (ind < 2) {
        /* fscanf(f,"%d",&i); */
        fscanf(f,"%f",&x);
        c1 = fgetc(f);
        c2 = fgetc(f);
        printf("%f%c%c; ",x,c1,c2);
        ++ind;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

A saida e exatamente a mesma.

Comment: Mas eu estou lendo de um arquivo txt, não direto do teclado.
Com 1.5x1+2.3x2 também da errado, tanto com %d quanto com %e.
Lendo um inteiro como no 1x1+2x2 com %d da certo. Gostaria de saber por que não consigo com %f ou %e, ele lê um valor totalmente aleatório nesses casos.

Comment: Ler de um arquivo da no mesmo. Se voce postar exatamente como esta seu arquivo posso tentar entender o que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Problema resolvido, lendo com %lf deu certo. De qualquer forma muito obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: Que bom. Lembre sempre que o ```scanf``` diferencia os tipos com ponto flutuante mas o ```printf```. nao.